# Why does my device only receive notification when I'm connected with 3G (Android GCM notifications)

Tags: android, android-c2dm, 3g

Everything works fine between my device, my 3rd-party server and the GCM-server.

I just can't understand why when I send a notification from my 3rd-party server my device can't receive it when it's connected with a Wi-Fi connection. The device only receive the notification when I disable the Wi-Fi connection and the device starts using the 3G connection.

Thank's

Comment: While you're on wifi connection, can your device access Google services like Android Market, Google Talk, Gmail, etc?

Comment: Yes I can access to the market and to gmail. Nevertheless I just tried if I could receive notifications from the gmail app when I'm on the Wi-Fi network and I can't... :s

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of some firewall settings on your current Wi-Fi network. Did you try it on multiple different Wi-Fi networks?

Comment: Yes I tried that on at least 2 differents networks, have anyone else experienced that with the old version of GCM (C2DM) ? I'll try to change the settings of the firewall when I get home, do you know what settings or which port I should open ?